# ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input[<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>]

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, valueerror

I am working on Face Mask Detection using Tensorflow and Keras.

The part of the Code that causes the error is:

```
new_model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 5, validation_split = 0.1)
```

The line of code **before** this is:

```
new_model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As per what I found online, I tried:

```
Y = np.array
```

But this didn't work

I really don't have much idea on how to fix this.

Request for a solution to this error

Comment: A solution for what exactly? Because the line Y = np.array makes no sense, np.array is a function and you are assigning the function itself to Y.

Comment: what are `X` and `Y`?  They have to be something like arrays.  Clearly they can't be functions.